# Using multiple #pragma directives on one function\variable

Tags: c, embedded, pragma, iar

Seems like a relatively simple question but I can not find a solid reference for the "right" way to attach several #pragma directives to one function or variable. I am using IAR and the legacy code is declared like this

```
__task  // don't save and restore registers
__root  // include function even if its is never called
void BootLoader( void ) @ "BOOTMAIN"  
{
    //..... code
}
```

I would like to use #pragma directives because the above syntax throws all my lint and autocomplete tools into chaos. But i can't find any examples of multiple #pragmas used together. Can I presume that all #pragma directives accumulate until an identifier is seen and then, after all being applied to that identifier, go away? enabling something like:

```
#pragma location="BOOTMAIN"
#pragma type_attribute=__task
#pragma object_attribute=__root
void bootloader(void)
{
    //..... code
}
```

Comment: `#pragma` semantics depend almost entirely on your compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using the IAR compiler

Comment: So you have the support as it is paid product.

Comment: unless using the free version. I am hoping to compare and contrast between the different compilers, although it seems like LLVM and GCC tend to use __attribute__() tags instead of #pragmas for this sort of thing. As stated in the question I want to compare and contrast how it works across different compilers since, at least for now, I have all my code checking tools set up to use LLVM and GCC. Maybe this is unrealistic, I don't know.

Comment: As far as I know you just use them as shown. Of course you have the `_Pragma("...")` alternative too, which should work in preprocessor defines. You should check out the *Pragma directives* and *Extended keywords* sections of the compiler manual for details.

Comment: Suck it and see would be the simplest approach.  The manual is perhaps ambiguous, but I would expect the directives to apply to the next valid symbol  regardless.